# How to collapse table rows into separate cards on mobile using CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-tables, visual-web-developer

I have a table that I want to collapse into separate cards on mobile devices. Here's the table code that I'm working with:

```
<table class="table-first">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Week</th>
      <th scope="col">Opponent</th>
      <th scope="col">Pass Yards Allowed</th>
      <th scope="col">Pass TDs Allowed</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="margin-bottom: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid;">
      <td data-title="Week">1</td>
      <td data-title="Opponent">Eagles</td>
      <td data-title="Pass Yards Allowed">239</td>
      <td data-title="Pass TDs Allowed">0</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Additional rows here -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried adding the following CSS code to collapse the table rows into separate cards on mobile:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .table-first tr {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
  }
  
  .table-first td {
    display: block;
  }

  .table-first td::before {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 6px;
    content: attr(data-title);
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

[It should look like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZXd9.png)
However, this code doesn't seem to work. Can someone please help me with the correct CSS code to collapse the table rows into separate cards on mobile devices? Thank you!

Comment: _"However, this code doesn't seem to work."_ - it pretty much does already. Your going to need to give the ::before pseudo elements a width though. The rest is adding the right margins/paddings, and borders.

Comment: And you probably want to hide the `thead` completely.